Finding the expectation of Gaussian a RV conditioned on affine transformation of jointly Gaussian Vector
Trying to solve a problem:
Consider the jointly gaussian vector $[X_0, X_1]^T$ where $X_0$ and $X_1$ are independent, zero-mean Gaussian RVs with variance $\sigma_0^2, \sigma_1^2$ respectively.
Then consider the affine transformation $Y_0 = aX_0 + bX_1$ and $Y_1 = cX_0 + dX_1$
In other words $Y=AX + b$ where $b=0$ and  $A = [\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix}]$
What is $E[X_0|Y_0,Y_1], P(X_0|Y_0,Y_1)$?
Is this stupidly easy and I'm just missing the point? I've seen plenty of examples where one conditions on one element of the transformed vector but have not found a specific example, where one conditions on both elements in the vector. Would be grateful for any help, thanks in advance for taking the time to answer this question!

The doctrine is the following: if $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian with covariance
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&B^T\\B&C\end{array}\right]$$ such that $C^{-1}$ exists, then $X|Y$ is Gaussian with expectation
$$E(X) +B^TC^{-1}(Y-E(Y))$$ and covariance $A-B^TC^{-1}B$ (independent of $Y$). Application: $X=X_0$, $Y=(Y_0,Y_1)$, with $A=\sigma^2_0$, $B^T=(a\sigma_0^2,c\sigma_0^2)$ and $$C=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a^2\sigma^2_0+b^2\sigma^2_1&ac\sigma^2_0+bd\sigma^2_1\\ac\sigma^2_0+bd\sigma^2_1&c^2\sigma^2_0+d^2\sigma^2_1\end{array}\right]$$ with $\det C=(ad-bc)^2\sigma^2_0\sigma^2_1.$

Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question. I have gathered, that the expectation of the (Gaussian) X|Y can be expressed as a vector of elements $[E[X_0|Y], E[X_1|Y]]^T = E[X|Y] = E[X] + cov(XY)cov(Y)^{-1}(Y - E[Y])$. Is that correct or am I misunderstanding something here. Unfortunately I suck at linear algebra and confuse things sometimes....

I have made some edit. In your case $E(X_0|Y_0,Y_1)$ is a number, and the covariance of  $X_0|(Y_0,Y_1)$ is also a number, the variance.

.... equal to $\sigma^2_0-B^TC^{-1}B$ a bit long expression to display here.
